# Paperclip gives error when image is not uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Paperclip works fine when I upload an image and then display it with:

```
<%= image_tag @post.photo.url(:medium) %>
```

The problem is, if an image wasn't uploaded, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show

Showing /Users/me/RubymineProjects/level_60/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I try to check and see if the image exists with `<% if @post.photo %>` or `<% if @post.photo != '' %>`.  However, both of those always return true even when there's no image uploaded.

How do I display an image through paperclip only if it exists?

Comment: try `<% if @post.photo.any? %>`

Comment: This is the error I get when I try that: `undefined method `any?' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x007ffa86e4be38>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that checking for `@post.photo` returns something that does not equal `false`, whatever it is. To debug this, simply print a `@post.photo.inspect` in your controller or view into your logfile.

Seeing that your comment already says it's a [`Paperclip::Attachment`](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Attachment) object, good candidates for checking would be `@post.photo.size > 0` or `@post.photo.errors.empty?`, or (probably best) `@phost.photo.file?`.